# php static methods question

Tags: php, oop

What is the difference between these two pieces of code?

```
class something {

   static function doit() {
      echo 'hello world';
   }
}

something::doit();
```

and the same but without the static keyword

```
class something {

   function doit() {
      echo 'hello world';
   }
}

something::doit();
```

They both work the same is it better to use the static keywords? Am i right in understanding that it doesn't instantiate the class if you use the static method?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The second example is technically incorrect - if you turn on E_STRICT error reporting you'll see that PHP is actually throwing an error.

> PHP Strict Standards:  Non-static
>   method something::doit() should not be
>   called statically in...

In other words, it's being nice and letting you call the function anyway.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the other valid answers, the reason for the 2nd example working is also due to a quirk in how PHP handles objects and calls (Besides PHP 4 compatibility).  Calling a non-`static` declared method statically from within another instance will let you access class methods on other classes as if they were local.  To understand, let's take an example:

```
class A {
    public function foo() {
        echo get_class($this) . "\n";
    }
}

class B {
    public function bar() {
        A::foo();
    }
}

$a = new a();
$a->foo(); // "A"
$b = new B();
$b->bar(); // "B"
```

Did you see what happened there?  Because you called the `A::foo()` method **from within another class's instance**, PHP treated the call as if it was on the same instance.  Note that there is no relationship between `A` and `B` other than the fact that `B` calls `A`.  Within `A->foo()`, if we did `$this instanceof A` (or `$this instanceof self`), it would fail and return false!  Quite unusual...

Now, I first thought it was a bug, but [after reporting it](http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=52969), it's apparently **as designed**.  It's [even in the docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php).

Note that this will not work with `E_STRICT` mode enabled.  It also will not work if you declare a method as `static`.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that static functions can be used without having to create an instance of the class.

Have a look at this great PHP OOP beginner tutorial [here](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/object-oriented-php-for-beginners/). It explains in more detail with an example under the *Static Properties and Methods* section.

Answer (score 0):

Second bit shouldn't work as you should call it by

```
$something = new something();
$something->doit();
```

Static functions allows you to call a function within a class without consturcting it.
So basically if you have a class to handle users, so a function that logs the user in should be a static function, as in the constructor of that class you will probably gather the user information and you cannot do so without logging him in.

Answer (score 0):

Your second example is wrong. Using a static method does not create an instance of the class. Your second example should look like this:

```
$x = new something();
$x->doit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Static methods should be declared static for minimum two reasons:
a) when using `E_STRICT` error_reporting, calling non static method as static will generate error:
`Strict standards: Non-static method something::doit() should not be called statically`
b) based on keyword `static` some IDE's filter method possible to run at auto-complete.