# php calling a non static method from a static method

Tags: php, oop, static

I've read a few questions on this in Java but I couldn't find what I was looking for in PHP - though these were quite close:
 [php static methods question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4884599/php-static-methods-question)
[Call method non-static with static in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22936085/call-method-non-static-with-static-in-php)

Is it possible to call a non static method from within a static?

I've a session class as below (called by `session::init()` ) but I can't work out how to avoid getting error messages.

```
<?php 
class session {

    public static function init(){
    if (**QUERY HERE**_is_session_started() === FALSE ) {
//      if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
            @session_start();   
        }   else {
            echo "Session already started<br/>";
        }
    }   


private function _is_session_started() {
    if ( php_sapi_name() !== 'cli' ) {
        if ( version_compare(phpversion(), '5.4.0', '>=') ) {
            return session_status() === PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE ? TRUE : FALSE;
        } else {
            return session_id() === '' ? FALSE : TRUE;
        }
    }
    return FALSE;
}

}
```

I only ever want the _is_session_started function to be called by the init() function - so it doesn't need to be static or public - but I'm not sure how to reference it.

If I replace **QUERY HERE** with 'self::' the page loads, but I get this error:

```
 PHP Strict Standards:  Non-static method session::_is_session_started() should not be called statically in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mvc/libs/session.php on line 5
```

But if I try to reference the method non-statically by using $this->_is_session_started() then I get a fatal error because the static init() function hasn't instantiated the session class.

So I'm thinking there must be another way to do this. I could make the _is_session_started method static  or just make my init function longer, but I'm keen to understand why this is.

Thanks

Comment: BTW, you may want to read [How Not To Kill Your Testability Using Statics](http://kunststube.net/static/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't make any sense to want to call a non-static method from a static one. To call a non-static method, you need an *object instance*. When you call a method statically, you have no object instance. I hope the discrepancy is obvious.

The point of non-static methods is that they have access to instance-specific data:

```
class Foo {

    public $bar;

    public function baz() {
        echo $this->bar;
    }

}

$a = new Foo;
$b = new Foo;

$a->bar = 'Hello';
$b->bar = 'World';

$a->baz();
$b->baz();
```

The `$this` keyword is the special sauce here. Since you do not have an object instance in a static method, i.e. no `$this`, you cannot call a non-static method:

```
Foo::baz();  // now what?
```

If your function uses `$this` and requires an object instance, you cannot call it statically. If your function does not use `$this` and does not require an object instance, make it `static` and call it statically.

Comment: Sounds like the answer is that it isn't possible. Which is interesting and I understand the logic.. I would have wanted to break up my static method if it had been possible, but I'll have to settle for combining it all in to one method instead.

Comment: That's not what I said. If your method is static (i.e. it doesn't use `$this`), then call it statically (i.e. `self::foo()`) **and mark it with the `static` keyword.**

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare the method `_is_session_started` as static.

```
private static function _is_session_started() {
```

Then call it with

```
self::_is_session_started();
```

Comment: Static functions do no have to be public. If the static function is only supposed to be called internally by the class itself (from other public static functions), they should not be public.

Comment: Thanks, but I mentioned I could change it to declare it statically in the original post - I'm querying because I only ever want to call this second method from within the init method (I'll never do session::_is_session_started) so I'm trying to find the best way to do that.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read that. As dceze mentioned you can also declare a static method as private. So you can call it with `self::_is_session_started`.

Comment: That gives me the strict error that non static methods shouldn't be called statically...

Comment: You have to declare it `static` **and** `private`.